# japanese ambiguous sentences

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, words, kanji

hello guys can you help me to translate this ambiguous sentence?

> これは道路の上に作られた細い溝と、その上を通るタイヤによって作られるのだが、制限速度で走らないと音楽らしい音楽に聞こえない。

translation: it is narrow gutter which is laid on top of road,

その上を通るタイヤによって作られるのだが->its  made according to car tire that pass on top of it(?)or it is made by laying tire on to of the street(?)(?) what is the meaning of によって in this sentence?
制限速度で走らないと音楽らしい音楽に聞こえない-> you cant hear the song if your car speed exceed the speed limit(?)

> ところが、その数はあまり増えなかった。それはメロディーロードからの音楽が騒音の元になるかもしれないという理由で、ほとんどが街中から離れたところに作られたからである。

それはメロディーロードからの音楽が騒音の元になるかもしれないという理由で->song in the melody road is noisy/it is made from the noisy sound(?)
ほとんどが街中から離れたところに作られたからである。because of that most of the road were built in the remote place from downtown.

> これらの短所を改善したり、新しいアイデアを付け足したりすれば、今のものとは違った活用方法や利用価値が見つけられるのではないだろうか。

from this weak point, try to add new idea, so we can find new practical use of this road and the value of using this road(?)

Comment: Almost right. I recommend that "you can't hear the song except appropriate speed. "

Comment: I think that we can hear the music only at the speed limit.

Comment: What book is this from? Just curious, it sounds like an interesting writing style (:

Comment: this passage is from speed master 読解日本語能力試験 n3 :)                                                      thanks for the fast reply :)                                                                               anyone also knows その上を通るタイヤによって作られるのだが this part meaning? それはメロディーロードからの音楽が騒音の元になるかもしれないという理由で and this 元になるmeaning?

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: Please post only one question per question.

Answer (score 2):

> これは道路の上に作られた細い溝と、その上を通るタイヤによって作られるのだが、制限速度で走らないと音楽らしい音楽に聞こえない。

This was created from the narrow gutter which lay upon the road and the tires which passed above it, but it didn't sound like music unless the car was going the speed limit.

> ところが、その数はあまり増えなかった。それはメロディーロードからの音楽が騒音の元になるかもしれないという理由で、ほとんどが街中から離れたところに作られたからである。

However, they had never built too many of these. This was because there was some concern that the music from Melody Road might become the source of noise, and most of them were built away from the city.

> これらの短所を改善したり、新しいアイデアを付け足したりすれば、今のものとは違った活用方法や利用価値が見つけられるのではないだろうか。

If there was a way to improve these drawbacks by the introduction of some new idea, then new ways to make use of these, along with some new benefits, might be found.

===

Does this answer your questions or do you want specific details about the expressions?

〜によって作られた => created using, created by means of, created as a result of

Comment: hello thanks so much! but i still dont get 〜によってmeaning in this sentence, could you explain more details? これは道路の上に作られた細い溝と、その上を通るタイヤによって作られるのだが -> this means the sound was created from the narrow gutter  which laid upon the road and was created by tire that pass through the street(?) -> 〜によってin this sentence explains the passive form, isnt it?

Comment: @DevinaMuljono: I think 「Aによって 」here is the agent of passive sentence, i.e., "by A" in English.

Comment: @DevinaMuljono: the "によって" means "By means of" the thing before it, which is actually two things: the "tires" and the "gutter".